# How the java script complex object and complex array iterate?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Below is running code snippet for the javascript object and array.
I have one jsonObj and here the ResultElementLevel could be the array or 
object.
According to I just put if else condition and compare if Array and 'object'.

My question is,How would it be  possible without if else condition?
can we write one function which compare object and Array inside single if.
The jsonObj is populating dynamically.
Here it would be possible *CHECK object* is also come into the Array or Object.

```js
var jsonObj = {

  "Response": {
    "Errors": {
      "Check": {
        "_attributes": {
          "id": "51416",
          "name": "lucyocftest090601"
        },
        "CheckLevel": {
          
        },
        "ResultElementLevel": {
          "_text": "Line No (2)  [Missing Reporting Category] "
        }
      }
    },
    "Success": {
      
    }
  }

}
iterateObjorArr(jsonObj);
function iterateObjorArr(jsonObj){
let checkArr = jsonObj.Response.Errors.Check;
 let checkID = checkArr._attributes.id;
 let checkName = checkArr._attributes.name;
 let status = 'failed';
 let resultElementLevel = checkArr.ResultElementLevel;
 let errorUploadArr = [];
 let errorUploadObj;
if (Array.isArray(resultElementLevel)) {
    
    resultElementLevel.map(function (data, index) {
        errorUploadObj = {
            'id': checkID,
            'checkName': checkName,
            'status': status,
            'errors/warnings': data._text
        };
        errorUploadArr.push(errorUploadObj);
    });
} else {
    if (typeof (resultElementLevel) === 'object') {
        errorUploadObj = {
            'id': checkID,
            'checkName': checkName,
            'status': status,
            'errors/warnings': resultElementLevel._text
        };
        errorUploadArr.push(errorUploadObj);
    }
}
console.log("errorUploadArr", errorUploadArr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test to see if `resultElementLevel` has the `length` property or not using `hasOwnProperty()`. Arrays have a length while objects do not (generally):

```
if (resultElementLevel.hasOwnProperty('length')) {
   // Handle it as an array
} else {
   // Handle as an object
}
```

This will, however, only work if the object assigned to `resultElementLevel` is guaranteed to not have a `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is,How would it be possible without if else condition? can we write one function which compare object and Array inside single if.

I don't think you'd want to get rid of the condition, but being able to deal with the passed data the same way, wether it's an array, a single item, or `null`/`undefined`

You could normalize the data first

```
function toArray(value){
    return value == null? []: 
        Array.isArray(value)? value: 
        //isArrayLike(value)? Array.from(value):
        [value];
}

//Objects that look like Arrays
function isArrayLike(value){
    return value !== null && typeof value === "object" && value.length === (value.length >>> 0);
}
```

so that from here on, you always deal with an Array:

```
let errorUploadArr = toArray(checkArr.ResultElementLevel)
    .map(function(item){
        return {
            id: checkID,
            checkName: checkName,
            status: status,
            "errors/warnings": item._text
        };
    });
```

```js
var jsonObj = {
  Response: {
    Errors: {
      Check: {
        _attributes: {
          id: "51416",
          name: "lucyocftest090601"
        },
        CheckLevel: {},
        ResultElementLevel: {
          _text: "Line No (2)  [Missing Reporting Category] "
        }
      }
    },
    Success: {}
  }
};

iterateObjorArr(jsonObj);



function toArray(value) {
  return value == null ? [] :
    Array.isArray(value) ? value :
    //isArrayLike(value)? Array.from(value):
    [value];
}

//Objects that look like Arrays
function isArrayLike(value) {
  return value !== null && typeof value === "object" && value.length === (value.length >>> 0);
}




function iterateObjorArr(jsonObj) {
  let checkArr = jsonObj.Response.Errors.Check;

  let checkID = checkArr._attributes.id;
  let checkName = checkArr._attributes.name;
  let status = "failed";

  let errorUploadArr = toArray(checkArr.ResultElementLevel)
    .map(function(data) {
      return {
        id: checkID,
        checkName: checkName,
        status: status,
        "errors/warnings": data._text
      }
    });

  console.log("errorUploadArr", errorUploadArr);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```